# How can merge audio and video in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio, video

I am creating a project in which, i merge video and audio using following code in objective c.

```
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
NSString *audio_inputFilePath = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SelectedSong.wav"];
NSURL    *audio_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audio_inputFilePath];
AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];

NSString *videoOutputPath = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Video.mp4"];
NSURL    *video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoOutputPath];
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];

CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);

AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
_assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
//_assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4 ;
//NSLog(@"support file types= %@", [_assetExport supportedFileTypes]);
_assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        };
```

---

but

```
 [[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]
```

it return empty array  in device.
when check it in simulator it work fine .

---

so please help me how can resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

In that case

`[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]`

`[b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];` this cannot read array.

Because Sound/Audio is not present in the particular file.This Error is comes only on those cases,When sound/Audio is not present in the perticular multimedia file.